# create hyperlink using cell value and some additional text in excel

Tags: excel

I have excel sheet containing column with values such as

```
BANDHANBNK
SRF
SRTRANSFIN
L&TFH
IBULHSGFIN
FEDERALBNK
PNB
PEL
VOLTAS
```

I want to create hyperlink for each of this, url can be created as

```
https://in.tradingview.com/chart/?symbol=NSE:ACC1!
```

so I need to concatenate

```
https://in.tradingview.com/chart/?symbol=NSE: + cell value + 1!
```

doing this manually is too much work, is there any simpler way to do this?

one more thing is if cell value contains & or - it should be converted to underscore.

Comment: last 1 is constant or it will increase 1 by 1.

Comment: it is a constant

Comment: Then try my answer.

Comment: it worked. can you tell me how to replace & or - by _ (underscore) while creating this link

Comment: Use `SUBSTITUTE()` function. See my edited answer. If it solve your problem then consider accepting the answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use following formula. Here simply concatenating cell value with `URL` then concatenate `1!`. Use `Hyperlink()` formula to make hyperlink.

```
=HYPERLINK("https://in.tradingview.com/chart/?symbol=NSE:" & A1 & "1!",A1)
```

[image]

To replace `&` and `-` by underscore `_` use below `SUBSTITUTE()` formula.

```
=SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(A1,"&","_"),"-","_")
```

[image]

Comment: i have created macro to open multiple hyperlinks at same time https://stackoverflow.com/q/65879870/14713550 . this macro works on hyperlinks that i create such as www.google.com , but somehow it doesnt work on the hyperlinks that  i create using the method you mentioned, can you tell me why this is happening

Comment: for more clearity, i have edited the question that i have mentioned above please look. @Harun24HR

Answer (score 1):

this worked for me.

```
=HYPERLINK("https://in.tradingview.com/chart/?symbol=NSE:" & SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(E2,"&","_"),"-","_") & "1!",E2)
```